# SSIS Execute Process Task - Passing Powerhell output into SSIS variable

Tags: powershell, ssis

thanks for the advices! Had taken note and edited my post accordingly, hopefully this time round I can get my question across clearer. :)

Currently, I am trying to use SSIS to run a Powershell script and wish to retrieve the output from that script and pass it on to the SSIS variable (string) named "User::TestStatus".

Had set breakpoint for the SSIS package to watch the variable "User::TestStatus" and noticed the value {20\r\n} being passed to it but when I continue with the package, the variable remains as an empty string variable.

Had tried using string functions like RTRIM/SUBSTRING as an expression to modify "User::TestStatus" but no value was assigned it at all when I run the package. I need to make use of "User::TestStatus" to do some check, what should I do to ensure that the return value from Powershell gets passed over to "User::TestStatus"?

Had attached some screenshots of the above details :) [PS script/SSIS task process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbXOj.png)

[Package Design Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixI3J.jpg)

Comment: No code, no images, no links - you need to provide a bit more information here :)

Comment: "Cleaning up the StandardOutputVariable" means something to you. As an SSIS practitioner with 18 years of experience, this is the first time I've seen someone reference such a task.  Take a moment, defrazle your brain, review the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and apply the pointers from the "How To Ask" article to your question.

Comment: What format is the output? (html, csv, text)

Comment: Hi guys! Had updated my post accordingly, hope you guys will take a look again when you are free :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen

Answer (score 0):

When/where is the variable loosing it's value? What task are you executing after the PS task?

I have re-created your PS script task followed by a C# script task to output the variable to the VS Output window and it works fine.

[image: VS SSIS Package]

Comment: Hi Paolo! After the PS task, I set it to execute cmd prompt with command ipconfig. Is the task after the PS script essential? I need to pass the value from PS to my SSIS variable so that I can set a constraint before the flow continues. My SSIS package is able to run too. I had set a breakpoint to observe the variable "User::TestStatus", it reflects the value {20\r\n} after the PS script runs but when the package is done executing, "User::TestStatus" still remains as an empty string. I think I missed out something somewhere along the way but I don't know what is it. helpppp T_T

Comment: @lsw No, the second script task in my example is not essential. Can you maybe post a screenshot of your ssis package designer and explain where you are having a problem?

Comment: Hi Paolo, had added in screenshots in my post for your reference! :)

Comment: @lsw the variable User::TestStatus is assigned a value by the PS script at **run time** and will only hold that value while the package is executing. The value assigned to the variable at **design time**, which in your case is empty, will not be affected by what happens at run time. If you want to keep the value of User::TestStatus after the package execution has completed you will have to add a task to your package to write that value to persistent storage, i.e. a database or file.

Comment: Got it Paolo! Took me some time to finally realized nothing went wrong at all...thanks a lot for your help! Kudos! :)

Answer (score 0):

In conclusion, when Execute Process Task node runs a PS script, the return value from the PS script gets passed into the StandardOutputVariable but the value of that variable always entails "\r\n". To get rid of this, I added an Expression Task following the Process Task with the expression "User::TestStatus = REPLACE(User::TestStatus, "\r\n", "")", now User::TestStatus becomes a clean string variable!

On a side note, I had one small discovery (not an exciting one). Within the Execute Process Task, if I enter the StandardOutputVariable from the "Expression" tab, the PS script return value gets passed into the literal named variable using the value of StandardOutputVariable instead of passing into StandardOutputVariable itself. For example, using two string variables "Test" and "Test1", under the expression tab, if I select StandardOutputVariable to be "Test", the return value will now be passed on to "Test1" instead. If you wish to assign the value to "Test" directly, choose it under the "General" tab instead.